# hide the keyboard on the button click

Tags: ios

I have used the IQKeyboardManager in my project .And i have set in the app delegate.

But i need to hide the iqkeyboardmanager while clicking on the button.How to do it.

currently my code in app delegate:-

```
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldShowToolbarPlaceholder = false
   IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
```

I have used tableview.So in the tableviewcell i have a button.  So while clicking on the button i need to hidden the keyboard .How to hide it?

Comment: Just call `view.endEditing()` in the button's selector.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Textfield then use this method for hide keyboard

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Otherwise, put this code in your button click method

```
[[IQKeyboardManager sharedManager] resignFirstResponder];
```

Here I found the best way to hide Keyboard on any screen.

1. Create Extension for **UIResponder**

   ```
   extension UIResponder {

        private static weak var _currentFirstResponder: UIResponder?

        static var currentFirstResponder: UIResponder? {
            _currentFirstResponder = nil
            UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.findFirstResponder(_:)), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)

            return _currentFirstResponder
        }

        @objc func findFirstResponder(_ sender: Any) {
            UIResponder._currentFirstResponder = self
        }

   }
   ```
2. How to use it

   ```
   UIResponder.currentFirstResponder?.resignFirstResponder()
   ```

Please prefer this link: https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/issues/659

Answer (score 0):

As you said in your question,
First of all, IQKeyboardManager is not a keyboard which you can hide or show. It is a library to manage scrolling and keyboard on views.

Now, you can hide the keyboard from tableCell on button click:
UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resign‌FirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)